# Skip successfully downloaded files using Wget

Tags: linux, bash, download, wget

So I have this Bash subroutine to download files using wget and my problem now is how to skip successfully downloaded files. The script downloads a lot of files and once the download fails, it re-downloads all files overwriting those successful downloads from the start (which may be incomplete because of the re-download).

So how do I skip those files downloaded successfully?

```
DownloadFile() {
  paramURL=$1
  paramFilename=$2

  if [ $flag_archive_fetch = "false"  ];
  then
      wget "--timeout=180" "--tries=5" "$paramURL" "-O" "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
  else
      unzip -o "$archive_file" "$paramFilename" -d "${scratch_dir}"
  fi

  touch "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of Wget `--continue` (to resume broken downloads) and [`--timestamping`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html) (to overwrite successfully downloaded files only when `Last-modified` attribute has changed, otherwise skips the download)

```
wget "--continue ‐‐timestamping --timeout=180" "--tries=5" "$paramURL" "-O" "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
```

another option is to use `--no-clobber` instead of `--timestamping`, it skips the already downloaded files without checking the `Last-modified` attribute,

```
 wget "--continue ‐‐no-clobber --timeout=180" "--tries=5" "$paramURL" "-O" "${scratch_dir}$paramFilename"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so --continue will skip already present files? I thought it was only for incomplete downloads.

Comment: --continue for incomplete downloads, and --timestamping for skip already downloaded files.

Comment: tried with --continue and --no-clobber but the problem with no clobber is that you can't continue unfinished downloads

Comment: "--no-clobber" should check if the file exists and not bother contacting the server, so how would it know whether or not the file is incomplete? "--continue" needs to check the size of the local file and the size on the server, so it needs to make a request to determine the size on the server in order to continue the download. These options are therefor in conflict with each other. ---- Woootiness needs to somehow record successful and unsuccessful downloads so that Woootiness can --no-clobber successfully downloaded file (or skip them entirely) or --continue if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you could check the [WGET exit status code](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) by checking the [`$?`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

```
wget .....
# store the error
error=$?
if (( $error != 0 )) 
then
   #handle error
else
   #handle success
fi
```