# Download file and unzip from Bash script file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm downloading a file and then unzipping it from a Bash script file.

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -N http://example.com/file.zip
unzip -o file.zip
```

Is there a way to check if `wget` actually downloaded a new file?  For instance, if the remote version of `file.zip` is the same as the local version it will not retrieve the file.  I only want to unzip the file if `wget` actually retrieves a new file.

Comment: Checksum and compare with previous value (stored in a txt somewhere)

Comment: Both `curl` and `wget` can be told not to download a file if it hasn't changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32322456/258523 for a recent question and answer about this for `wget`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check return value and output from `wget` to figure out whether file has been downloaded:

```
out=$(wget -qN 'http://example.com/file.zip' 2>&1)
[[ $? -eq 0 && $out ]] && unzip file.zip
```

If `file.zip` is already there with same timestamp then `wget` will not download it and nothing will be written to stdout/stderr making `out` variable empty.

Comment: I'm getting an error "[[: not found" on the last line.  Also, is it possible to have it display the output when you assign it to out?

Comment: `[[` not found means you're not using bash. Make sure to use `bash` when you run this. To display output you can add `echo "$out"` after first line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Last-Modified header, that's dependent on the server.  Anubhava@'s also works but this is less overhead and slightly more portable between Bourne shell variations:

This gets you what you need:

```
wget -N http://example.com/file.zip 2>&1  | grep "not retrieving" 2>&1 > /dev/null || unzip file.zip
```

1. Get file
2. Redirect stderr to stdout
3. Check if "not retrieving" is in output (what wget prints when it's not downloading the file)
4. If the "not retrieving" string does not exist in ouput, grep returns error code '1' and the file is unzipped.  Otherwise, it just moves on silently.

It's essentially saying this, with more detail added for readability:

```
out=$(wget -N http://example.com/file.zip 2>&1)
if [ $(echo $(out) | grep "not retrieving") ]; then
    echo "No new file; not unzipping"
else
    unzip file.zip
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but don't work anymore.
I don't have any return when I set the quiet option of wget in the 2 case but we can have the HTML Code with the -S option of wget.

-200 if the file is downloaded

-304 if is the same file

-others... for all "bad" situations

a solution without change the @anubhava method's :

```
out=$(wget -SN 'http://example.com/file.zip' 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}')
[[ $out -eq 200 ]] && unzip file.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
curl -I http://example.com/file.zip
```

and check `Last-Modified:` value.

You may also use `wget --timestamping` but requesting HEAD info you have more control.